# React - Updating a component's state with the same value triggers a render

Tags: reactjs

When I use useState several times with the same value as the previous value, the component is executed once and then nothing.

From what I understand so far, when the state is updated with the same value, nothing should happen.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  console.log('RENDER')

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(0)}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

If I press the + button several times (let's say 3 times), the state changes and the component is executed 3 times. The RENDER message is also displayed in the console each time.

If now I press the reset button several times. I have the message RENDER which is displayed twice then nothing.

The first time because the state changes, 3 to 0.
The second time, the state is the same. So why is RENDER displayed again in the console?

Answer (score 2):

This should give you some idea

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

> If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely.

This essentially means that when your `setState(0)` gets called the first time, it returns `0` but the current state is `3` which the virtual DOM evaluates it as a requirement to update the real DOM causing the re-render to occur. This also tells the virtual DOM to **cause** subsequent re-renders too.

The second time you call `setState(0)` the current state is `0` and the value to set is also `0` which means there should not be any subsequent re-renders based on the value `0` but a re-render should be performed to update the virtual and real DOM to have a "locked" state of `0`. Again, subsequent re-renders based on the value `0` won't be triggered.