# Why does the component re-render when useCallback is used with an empty array?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning about the `useCallback` hook in React. There is an online demo accessible at https://codesandbox.io/s/red-sun-mw86q2?file=/src/App.js that I'm working with, and I've run into an issue - why is 'App is re-rendering' still being printed to the console when I click the button a second time? Can someone explain this for me this case, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing example code. it will render when you put state at dependency of your useCallback fun.

Answer (score 0):

#### re-render useCallback()

Hi, you should try to put your state data inside of dependency of usecallback function.

pls try like this, it will re-render.

```
const increment = useCallback(
    function () {
      setCount(count + 1);
    },
    [count]
  );
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-http-kvvytj?file=/src/App.js:248-347)

ref: [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback). if you want a state or props to be reactive value, you should put that variable at dependency like `useCallback(fun, [var1, var2])`

```
useCallback(fn, dependencies)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand the normal usage is what you described. However, in my example, when I click the button for the second time, the old and new value of count are both 1. So the component should not re-render in this case, right?

Comment: I see now what you mean. I saw a question same as your meaning.

Comment: here the question, hope that help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483739/react-updating-a-components-state-with-the-same-value-triggers-a-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483739/react-updating-a-components-state-with-the-same-value-triggers-a-render)

Comment: Thanks! I've read that question and related answers. I also found another similar question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652176/react-hooks-usestate-setvalue-still-rerender-one-more-time-when-value-is-equal). After reading [@sophiebits's comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14810#issuecomment-462089702)(if what she said is correct), I understand that this is because the updates are not processed until the render phase.